# jump box when drag in another point how fix jump

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

Jump box when drag in another point how fix jump.

These are my codes here:

```
$('.box_reminded_pop,.boxing').draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".line",
    containment: '.day_table ',
});
```

When I remove this section all work fine but the html content of the dragged box not goes here:

```
$(".line").sortable({
    revert: true,
});
```

Comment: i most be use this fn for slove

Comment: i most be use this fn for slove   "function dragBox($item, droppedItem)"